# What is the difference between normal and special edition?

Tags: version-differences, harvest-moon-a-wonderful-life

[Harvest Moon: A Wonderful life (Special Edition)](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/harvest-moon-a-wonderful-life-special-edition/cid=UP1014-CUSA06584_00-SLUS211710000001) was recently released on the PS4.

I also have this normal edition of game on the GameCube. **What are the differences between the normal edition and the "Special Edition"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent PS4 rerelease appears to be a rerelease of the PS2 version of Harvest Moon: A Wonderful Life Special Edition. Thus, the differences between the GameCube and PS4 versions would be almost the same as the differences between the PS2 and GameCube versions, with the addition of trophy support. These differences are, according to the [wikia](http://harvestmoon.wikia.com/wiki/Harvest_Moon:_A_Wonderful_Life_Special_Edition):

> - Lumina is now eligible for marriage
> - The choice to a daughter
> - New Animals
> - Goat can be sold
> - A "Heaven Mode" or free-play mode is unlocked after the game's ending.
> - Mukumuku's appearance.
> - The second chapter is called "A Birth", in AWL, it is called "Happy Birthday".
> - New Dialogues
> - A few cooking changes

Comment: thanks for the info here, I didn't even know they had a PS2 version. :D